# How to change json array format in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have php script which is storing data into an array and then converting into json array. Following is script

```
$gameTraining = array();
$index = 0;
foreach($todayTraining->toArray() as $training){
    if($todayTraining[$index]['type'] === 'easy'){
        $gameTraining['easy'][]['game_id'] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
    }
    $index++;     
}
return $gameTraining;
```

And following response I am getting

```
{
    "training": {
        "easy": [
            {
                "game_id": 12
            },
            {
                "game_id": 6
            },
            {
                "game_id": 26
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But I would like to remove the brackets from array, so can you kindly guide me how can I do that? I would like to convert as following

```
{
    "training": {
        "easy": [
                "game_id": 12,
                "game_id": 6,
                "game_id": 26
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output is not a Valid JSON

Comment: Your using `foreach()` to give you the element in `$training`, but then you are getting values from `$todayTraining[$index]` where you are maintaining `$index` yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have multiple items in an array with the same key. You can make an array with the ids for the game, so this line:

```
$gameTraining['easy'][]['game_id'] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
```

can be changed with this line:

```
$gameTraining['easy']['game_ids'][] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
```

Comment: @RakeshJakhar, the key was set to `game_ids` on purpose, because it will contain multiple ids, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$todayTraining = [
    [
        'type' => 'easy',
        'game_id' => 123
    ],
    [
        'type' => 'easy',
        'game_id' => 456
    ]
];
$gameTraining = array();
$index = 0;
foreach($todayTraining as $training){
    if($todayTraining[$index]['type'] === 'easy'){
        $gameTraining['easy'][] = substr(json_encode(['game_id' => $todayTraining[$index]['game_id']]), 1, -1);
    }
    $index++;
}
echo json_encode($gameTraining, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below line :

```
$gameTraining['easy'][] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
```

Instead of :

```
$gameTraining['easy'][]['game_id'] = $todayTraining[$index]['game_id'];
```

Hopefully, it will work.